# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, Database Content Provider "my apps is force close"

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-contentprovider

I create database applications via the Content Provider, but there is an error, I do not know how to fix it, I've tried but it's still an error. please help her from the experts :) thanks

> 12-29 18:57:00.333 31234-31234/com.example.arf_amella.rencana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.arf_amella.rencana, PID: 31234
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arf_amella.rencana/com.example.arf_amella.rencana.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: rencana (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM rencana
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: rencana (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM rencana
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1112)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:689)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1613)
>                                                                                       at com.example.arf_amella.rencana.RencanaKerja.delete(RencanaKerja.java:109)
>                                                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:273)
>                                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1282)
>                                                                                       at com.example.arf_amella.rencana.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**DBhelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Berisi perintah SQL untuk menciptakan Tabel bernama artis
private final static String BUAT_TABEL = "create table" +
        Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL + " (" +
        Konstanta.ID_RENCANA + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        Konstanta.SIFAT_RENCANA + " text not null, " +
        Konstanta.NAMA_RENCANA + " text not null);";


public DBHelper(Context konteks) {
    super(konteks, Konstanta.NAMA_DB, null, Konstanta.VERSI_DB);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(BUAT_TABEL);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versilama, int versibaru) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

**Konstanta.java**

```
public class Konstanta {

public final static String NAMA_DB = "dbrencana";
public final static int VERSI_DB = 1;
public final static String NAMA_TABEL = "rencana";
public final static String ID_RENCANA = "id";
public final static String NAMA_RENCANA = "nama";
public final static String SIFAT_RENCANA = "sifat";
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
EditText editTextRencana = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new  AdRequest.Builder().build();


    //Mendeklarasikan Interstitial

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            displayInterstitial();


        }
    });

    //Hapus Semua Record jika ada

    getContentResolver().delete(RencanaKerja.URI_ISI,
                                                null,
                                                null);

    //Tambahkan data
    simpan("Main Tenis", "Biasa");
    simpan("Rapat Hari Rabu", "Penting");
    simpan("Tugas Pemrograman Web", "Penting");
    simpan("Main Futsal", "Biasa");

    //Tampilkan Data
    ArrayList<String> listData = perolehanData();

    final ListView listViewData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRencana);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public void simpan(String rencana, String sifat) {
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put(RencanaKerja.NAMA_RENCANA, rencana);
    data.put(RencanaKerja.SIFAT_RENCANA, sifat);
    getContentResolver().insert(RencanaKerja.URI_ISI, data);


}

private ArrayList<String> perolehanData() {
    ArrayList<String> hasil = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri semuaRencana = RencanaKerja.URI_ISI;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            semuaRencana,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            String namaRencana = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nama"));
            String sifatRencana = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sifat"));

            hasil.add(namaRencana + " (" + sifatRencana + ") ");
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return hasil;
}





private void displayInterstitial() {

    //Meneampilkan Interestitial
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()){
        interstitial.show();
    }

}
```

}

**RencanaKerja.java**

```
public class RencanaKerja extends ContentProvider {

public static final String NAMA_PROVIDER = "com.example.arf_amella.rencana";
public static Uri URI_ISI = Uri.parse("content://" +
                                        NAMA_PROVIDER + "/rencana");
public static final String _ID = Konstanta.ID_RENCANA;
public static final String NAMA_RENCANA = Konstanta.NAMA_RENCANA;
public static final String SIFAT_RENCANA =  Konstanta.SIFAT_RENCANA;

private static final int RENCANA = 1;
private static final int ID_RENCANA = 2;

private DBHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dbRencana;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    uriMatcher.addURI(NAMA_PROVIDER, "rencana", RENCANA);
    uriMatcher.addURI(NAMA_PROVIDER, "rencana/#", ID_RENCANA);

}

//Dipanggil Saat Content Provider Dipanggil

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
    dbRencana = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (dbRencana == null) ? false : true;

}




//Memberi tipe MIME data untuk URI yg diberikan

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

//Menambahkan Record baru ke content Provider

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues cv) {
    long IDBaris = dbRencana.insert(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, null, cv);
    if (IDBaris > 0 ){
        Uri sUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(URI_ISI, IDBaris);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(sUri, null);

        return sUri;

    }
  throw new SQLException("Gagal Menyisipkan Data Ke "+ uri);
}

// Mengubah Data disuatu Record Content Provider

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues cv, String seleksi, String[] argSeleksi) {
    int tipeUri = uriMatcher.match(uri);
    int cacah = 0;

    switch (tipeUri){
        case  RENCANA:
            cacah = dbRencana.update(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL,cv,seleksi,argSeleksi);
            break;
        case ID_RENCANA:
            cacah = dbRencana.update(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL,cv,_ID+" = "+uri.getPathSegments().get(1),null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI " + uri + " tidak dikenal");
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return cacah;

}

//menghapus Record pada Content PROVIDER
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String seleksi, String[] argSeleksi) {

    int tipeUri = uriMatcher.match(uri);
    int cacah = 0;

    switch (tipeUri) {
        case RENCANA:
            cacah = dbRencana.delete(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, seleksi, argSeleksi);
            break;
        case ID_RENCANA :
            cacah = dbRencana.delete(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, _ID + " = "+ uri.getPathSegments().get(1), null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI" + uri + " tidak dikenal ");
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    return cacah;
}


// Memproses Query

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] proyeksi, String seleksi, String[] argSeleksi, String pengurutan) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqLBuilder.setTables(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL);

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == ID_RENCANA)
        sqLBuilder.appendWhere(Konstanta.ID_RENCANA + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
    if (pengurutan == null || pengurutan == "")
        pengurutan = Konstanta.NAMA_RENCANA;

    Cursor c = sqLBuilder.query(dbRencana, proyeksi, seleksi, argSeleksi, null, null, pengurutan);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return c;
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <provider
        android:name="RencanaKerja"
        android:authorities="com.example.arf_amella.rencana"
        android:exported="true"
        />
```

Comment: "create table" -> "create table "

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.. @pskink

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `try`/`catch`, which suppresses any useful error messages. Drop it.

(In this case, the message would have shown the missing space after the `CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: how to fix it..? @CL.